# Is this linear operator surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear operator $f_A$ on $K^{n×n}$ defined by $f_A(X)=AX-XA$ where $K$ is field. Is $f_A$ is surjective? If no, then under what conditions $f_A$ is surjective?

**My attempt**: I can see easily that $f_A$ is not surjective if I take $K=\mathbb{R}$. Hence in general $f_A$ is not surjective.

**But I am not able to determine the condition under which $f_A$ is surjective**.

It is given in a **hint** that, if $char(K)$ does not divide $n,$ then $f_A$ is not surjective. So **does that mean,** if I consider $K$ to be a finite field having characteristic which divides $n,$ then $f_A$ is surjective? How? Please help!

Comment: It's surjective iff its injective, but $I$ is always in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Examine the trace of $f_A(X)$.

Comment: Sir trace of $f_A(X)=0$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi, right. And do all matrices have zero trace?

Comment: Sir, yes identify matrix does not have zero trace and hence $f_A$ is not surjective. But I didn't understand what and why in hint it is given that "if charK does not divides $n$ then $f_A$ is not surjective?

Comment: If $\mbox{char}K$ does not divide $n$, then $I_n$ is not trace zero.